# PHP Codeigniter Database select by date

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I have this table:

```
--
-- Table structure for table `tweets`
--

CREATE TABLE `tweets` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `url` text NOT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `source` text NOT NULL,
  `img` text NOT NULL,
  `date` datetime NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
```

I try to select the records from a time interval using this code:

```
$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $begin)->getTimestamp();
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $end)->getTimestamp();

$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimestamp($end);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
$date->sub(new DateInterval('PT1S'));
$end = $date->getTimestamp();

$this->db->where('date >=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$begin));
$this->db->where('date <=', date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$end));
```

But this code isn't working so well because I get some records that aren't in that timeframe. Any thoughts ?
I have the timestamp of the first and last day of the interval and I need to select all records from the DB in that time interval.

Thanks!

Comment: I think this `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",$begin)` will output `1970-01-01`. Need to change it to `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($begin))` and `date("Y-m-d H:i:s",strtotime($end))`

Comment: @NanaPartykar I get the timestamp here: `$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/d/Y', $begin)->getTimestamp();`
I think it might be sth with the time zone.